# Godot: detect "mouse down" inside Area2D and "mouse up" OUTSIDE Area2D

Tags: mouse, godot, gdscript

I want to detect a mouse click (and hold) inside an Area2D, and then detect the mouse release both inside or outside the Area2D.

Here's what I have so far:

```
extends Area2D #PickArea

func _input_event(viewport, event, shape_idx):
    if event is InputEventMouseButton and event.button_index == BUTTON_LEFT:
        if event.is_pressed():
            print("picked")
        else:
            print("released")    ## here be dragons. release only detected inside Area2D
```

The above works but it only detects the mouse release inside the Area2D. How do I detect the mouse release also outside the Area2D?

Here's the node structure:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get input events outside of the `Area2D` in `_input`. Use that to get the release:

```
func _input(event: InputEvent) -> void:
    if (
        event is InputEventMouseButton
        and event.button_index == BUTTON_LEFT
        and not event.is_pressed()
    ):
        print("released")
```

However, you would only want to get that after you got the press, right? So, let us disable `_input` on `_ready` and on `_input`, and enable it on `_input_event`:

```
extends Area2D

func _ready():
    set_process_input(false)

func _input_event(viewport: Object, event: InputEvent, shape_idx: int) -> void:
    if (
        event is InputEventMouseButton
        and event.button_index == BUTTON_LEFT
        and event.is_pressed()
    ):
        print("picked")
        set_process_input(true)

func _input(event: InputEvent) -> void:
    if (
        event is InputEventMouseButton
        and event.button_index == BUTTON_LEFT
        and not event.is_pressed()
    ):
        print("released")
        set_process_input(false)
```

That should do the trick.