# Godot: InputEventScreenTouch detects press, but doesnt detect when released outside

Tags: godot

I've made an `Area` mesh and collision shape in it (it's a 3D simple square):

[image: Area with whatever it takes to have it working]

Then in the `Area` "barillet", I'm detecting the touch:

```
extends Area

func _input_event(camera, event, position, normal, shape_idx):
    if event is InputEventScreenTouch:
        print("touch : ", event, " -> ", event.is_pressed())
```

I've changed my settings so that the mouse emulates the ScreenTouch, and everything works fine: when I click on the `Area`, I see in the log: `touch : [InputEventScreenTouch:1463] -> True`. And this means `event.is_pressed()==True`.

If I release **while in the `Area`** it works: I see in the log: `touch : [InputEventScreenTouch:1487] -> False`

If I release **outside the `Area`** nothing happens.

How do I detect it's been released *outside* the `Area`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Godot: detect "mouse down" inside Area2D and "mouse up" OUTSIDE Area2D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69498580/godot-detect-mouse-down-inside-area2d-and-mouse-up-outside-area2d)

Comment: No, because it's in 3D, not 2D. This changes everything.

Comment: You want 3D and touch, that one is 2D and mouse. It changes very little. But, sure, I'll rewrite it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get input events outside of the `Area` in `_input`. Use that to get the release:

```
func _input(event: InputEvent) -> void:
    if (
        event is InputEventScreenTouch
        and not event.is_pressed()
    ):
        print("released")
```

However, you would only want to get that after you got the press, right? So, let us disable `_input` on `_ready` and on `_input`, and enable it on `_input_event`:

```
extends Area

func _ready():
    set_process_input(false)

func _input_event(camera: Object, event: InputEvent, position: Vector3, normal:Vector3, shape_idx:int) -> void:
    if (
        event is InputEventScreenTouch
        and event.is_pressed()
    ):
        print("picked")
        set_process_input(true)

func _input(event: InputEvent) -> void:
    if (
        event is InputEventScreenTouch
        and not event.is_pressed()
    ):
        print("released")
        set_process_input(false)
```

That should do the trick.

---

**Addendum**: Being this for touch, you may want to also remember `index`, for multi-touch support:

```
extends Area

var drag_index := -1

func _ready():
    set_process_input(false)

func _input_event(camera: Object, event: InputEvent, position: Vector3, normal:Vector3, shape_idx:int) -> void:
    if (
        event is InputEventScreenTouch
        and event.is_pressed()
    ):
        print("picked")
        drag_index = (event as InputEventScreenTouch).index
        set_process_input(true)

func _input(event: InputEvent) -> void:
    if (
        event is InputEventScreenTouch
        and (event as InputEventScreenTouch).index == drag_index
        and not event.is_pressed()
    ):
        drag_index = -1
        print("released")
        set_process_input(false)
```

*I'll also mention that you could handle `InputEventScreenDrag` for drag, but if you only care about release, that is not necesary.*

Comment: Your answer is more than useful, I've added it to a good french forum thanks a lot!